# Como não deixar imagem aparecer no arrastar?

Tags: php

Sabe quando você coloca uma imagem em um site, e quando você clica nela e segura ela fica pequinininha e da pra arrastar né?

Como fazer para não deixar o usuário arrastar e nem salvar imagem?
O instagram por exemplo você não consegue salvar a imagem e nem arrastar ela.

Comment: Se as imagens não tiverem num slideshow, use este código de `css`: `img{ pointer-events: none; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Esta é uma sugestão com base nos meus conhecimentos. Provavelmente existem outras formas de fazer.*

1 - colocar a imagem como background e NÃO com a tag `<img>`. Assim:

```
<style>

.img {
    background-image: url('imagem/minhaImagem.jpg');
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

</style>

<div class="img">

</div>
```

Desta forma ele não irá conseguir arrasta a imagem, ou copia-la. Porém, ele irá conseguir descobrir o caminho dela.

2 - Bloquear o acesso do diretório de imagens com `.htaccess`. Você cria um arquivo com esse nome **.htaccess** dentro do diretorio que você quer bloquear o acesso. No caso **imagens**. Neste arquivo, você insere o seguinte código:

```
<Directory /imagens> // <-- é necessário colocar o nome do diretório
    Options -Indexes 
</Directory>
```

E todas suas imagens estarão inacessíveis.